I need to add a specific value in a cell, (new column, same row) if a cell is yellow
I'd like to have
From this:

To this:

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('AG Construction.xlsx',data_only=True)
workbook = load_workbook(filename='AG Construction.xlsx')

fs = wb.active
fs_count_row = fs.max_row 
fs_count_col = fs.max_column 
for riga in range(1,fs_count_row+1):
    for colonna in range(1,fs_count_col+1):
        cell_color = fs.cell(column=colonna, row=riga)
        bgColor = cell_color.fill.bgColor.index
        fgColor = cell_color.fill.fgColor.index
        if (bgColor=='00000000') or (fgColor=='00000000'):
            continue
        else:
            print("Riga (",riga,colonna, ") is", bgColor)

but I don't know how to get the result
I've tried to use wb.cell but seams don't work.

What logic is used to make the cell yellow? use that logic to control the value.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

wb.cell is not valid, 'wb' is a workbook which does not have a 'cell' attribute. Only Sheets have cells. However wb['Sheet1'].cell(1,1) is valid since wb['Sheet1'] is a worksheet object.

As mentioned in the comments, identifying the filled cell will be dependent on how the fill colour is applied, and what the actual colour make up is.
Assuming its Format Cell ---> Fill as your code suggests and the colour is yellow, (FFFF00) you can search that column for cells that match, then enter the value in the last + 1 column.
Also note
If you use data_only=True when opening your workbook, you will lose all formulas in the Sheet(s). It appears at least column 'G' is a calculation, so if you opened with that param set True and saved the updated workbook over the original, all formulas will be over-written by the current value.
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('AG Construction.xlsx')
fs = wb.active

new_column = max((c.col_idx for c in fs[2])) + 1

### Add Header for new column
fs.cell(row=2, column=new_column, value="Input")
fs.cell(row=2, column=new_column).font = Font(bold=True)

for cell in fs['F']:  # Iterate cells in column F only
    print(cell.fill.fgColor.rgb)  # Check cell fill colour
    if cell.fill.fgColor.rgb == 'FFFFFF00':  # Yellow fill
        ### Use offset to place 'input' on same row
        cell.offset(column=new_column - cell.column).value = 'input'

wb.save('AG Construction.xlsx')

